# Definition of Identity Matrix

Tags: matrices

Is the below matrix an Identity Matrix?
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{A}= 
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0  & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 1  & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0  & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 0  & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
As \begin{equation*} \mathbf{A^{-1}} = \mathbf{A} \end{equation*}
 \begin{equation*} \mathbf{A^{-1}}\cdot\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{A}\end{equation*}

Comment: No, this is not the identity. It has 1 on the diagonal and 0 else.

Comment: @Fakemistake But from definition of inverse A multiplied by its inverse should give Identity matrix while this gives A?

Comment: What is the value of the determinant of your matrix?

Comment: No, the identity $A$ is defined, such that for every nice matrix $B$ we have $AB=B$

Comment: @Kevin Determinant is 1

Comment: If the size is 3, then the determinant is -1.

Comment: @Fakemistake Then is the definition given in this link for Inverse wrong http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixInverse.html ? As this  seems to violate it.

Comment: Excuse me for being a bit pedantic but if we are taking $A' \cdot B'$ and $\cdot$ denotes the usual matrix multiplication then no, $A$ is not the identity, but it could be w.r.t some multiplication. So one thing to take from this is, the identity is defined by the binary operation, but not all binary operations have one.

Comment: @mathworker No this definition says nothing about $A^{-1}=A$ what you wrote in the question. Please read the definition carefully.

Comment: Thank you all, I seem to have multiplied matrices wrong A*A^{-1} is I indeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly not true that $A^{-1}A=A$ for this $A$. On the standard basis,
$$ Ae_1 = e_4,\quad Ae_2=e_3,\quad Ae_3 = e_2,\quad Ae_4=e_1, $$
so $A^2e_i = e_i$ for all $i$. Hence $A^{-1}=A$, but $A^{-1}A=A^2$ has matrix
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \neq A. $$

Comment: Thank you I seems to multiplying matrices all wrong. Need to go back to basics :(

Answer (score 2):

The definition of the identity matrix is a matrix $I$ such that for every matrix $A$
$$AI= IA =A$$ However your matrix does not satisfy this condition. What you've listed are just properties of $I$ not the definition

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not.

An identity matrix $A$ should verify $X.A=A.X=A$ for all $X\in M_{4,4}$.

Here it is easy to find a counterexample, for instance if $B=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\ \end{bmatrix}$ you have $A.B=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\1&0&0&0\\ \end{bmatrix}\neq B$

Meanwhile, you assertion $A^{-1}.A=A$ is incorrect. How did you find that ?

Comment: I found the inverse using row manipulation and cross checked it with this -> http://ncalculators.com/matrix/4x4-inverse-matrix-calculator.htm

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo.